# Can Dreamweaver work with Bitbucket ? If yes how to setup

Tags: svn, dreamweaver, bitbucket

I have DW CS6 and trying to connect to my Bitbucket account with

Server and project are not accessible! (OPTIONS of 'https://myaccountname@bitbucket.org:443/myaccountname': 200 OK (https://bitbucket.org))

I'm Selecting:

Access: Subversion 
Protocol: HTTPS
Server Address: https://myaccountname@bitbucket.org/myaccountname/myproject.git
Server Path: Empty
Server Port: 443
Username: myusername
Password: mypassword

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

- DW can use **only** Subversion as SCM
- Bitbucket support **only** Mercurial and Git

Thus:

you can't use DW+BB, but can Github, which provide transparent access to Git-repos to SVN-clients (using special URL). But, anyway, native Subversion hosting will be better and more easy way

Comment: I just downloaded DW CC 2015 and still the only supported method is Subversion. Isn't that retarded, since Git is pretty much used everywhere nowadays?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure how it works but it can be done on a windows machine. I found an article here called [The mysterious Git: Using Git with Dreamweaver and Bitbucket](http://bbdokc.com/blog/the-mysterious-git-using-git-with-dreamweaver-and-bitbucket). Also here is a [github page](https://github.com/ChrisMcKee/gitweaver) for the GITWeaver plugin.